# How to properly treat deletions in a Postgres SQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm working on setting up a SQL database for tracking workouts, and I'm unsure how to handle deletions. Here are a few relevant tables from my schema:

**Template**
A template is a type of workout (e.g. "Leg Workout")

```
id serial PRIMARY KEY
user_id integer
   REFERENCES User(id)
   NOT NULL
   ON DELETE CASCADE
name varchar(255) NOT NULL
UNIQUE(user_id, name)
```

**Movement**
A movement is a specific exercise (like a Squat)

```
id serial PRIMARY KEY
user_id
   REFERENCES User(id)
   NOT NULL
   ON DELETE CASCADE
name UNIQUE NOT NULL
UNIQUE(user_id, name)
```

**CompletedWorkout**
A completed workout is exactly what it sounds like — a workout that someone completed based on a template

```
id serial PRIMARY KEY
date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
template_id integer
    REFERENCES Template(id)
    NOT NULL
comment varchar(1536)
```

**Completed Exercise**
A completed exercise is a specific exercise (with reps and weights) inside of a completed workout. For example, a Squat on Leg day with 5 reps of 200lbs would be one completed exercise.

```
id serial PRIMARY KEY
completed_workout_id integer
    REFERENCES CompletedWorkout(id)
    NOT NULL
movement_id integer
    REFERENCES Movement(id)
    NOT NULL
reps integer
weight_lbs integer DEFAULT 0
```

So here's my question — what should I do when someone deletes a Template or a Movement?

I still want the CompletedWorkout table to know the name of the template before it was deleted. For example, someone might delete their "Leg Workout" template, but if they had already completed a "Leg Workout", the database record in the "CompletedWorkout" table should know that.

I'm not quite sure about the right way to make this happens. Since with the current setup deleting a record inside of the `Template` table would leave a row inside of the `CompletedWorkout` table that has a `template_id` that doesn't exist.

Any idea on the right way to implement this? Appreciate the help!

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL, as the title implies, why also tag MySQL and SQL Server? What does the question have to do with *all* 3 of those products?

Comment: 1) Do not use type names for field names e.g. `date`. That will only cause confusion. 2) Be wary of using mixed case names like `Template`. If you want to maintain the mixed case you will need to double quote the name everywhere you use it as in: `"Template"`. That includes creating the table. 3) Why delete `Template`? Instead add a `boolean` `active` field and and/or a `deactivated_date` `date` field.

Comment: Got it, thanks! If I'm not going to use mixed case table names, what's the best practice for naming tables with multiple words. Should I use underscores like `completed_workout`? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: That is what I do as `-`(hyphen) would need to be quoted also. For more information see [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the basic information, you should do what is called a "soft delete": include a column in the table called "Active" or "Deleted", and merely update the value of that column. Then you must also account for this new column in various retrieval operations.

Often, for this type of data you also want to know the date of the deletion, so the column might be named "DeletedDate", where a NULL value means the item was not deleted yet.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Why would I typically want to know the deletion date?

Comment: Not necessarily "typically"... just "often".